# Does Silverlight 4 install on a non-Intel Mac?

Tags: silverlight

Does Silverlight 4 install on a non-Intel Mac?

Comment: http://superuser.com/ would be a more suitable community to ask this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  This link implies that only Silverlight 1 is installable on a PPC Mac.  [Apple Downloads site](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/development_tools/silverlight.html). Anything later requires OSX 10.5 or higher, which is Intel-only.

Here's [another link](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/faq/#sys-req), from Microsoft's FAQ site, which states OSX 10.4.8 or higher.  Again, OSX 10.4.8 is Intel only.